# applying concurrency when a ConcurrentHashMap is map value

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Multiple threads will try to update values of same mainCode, does below cause trouble? Also another job will consistently read values of securities and apply operations if values match.

```
public class MyObj {

        private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Model>> securities = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
        private static void updateModel(String mainCode, String code, BigDecimal valueA, BigDecimal valueB) {
            securities.compute(mainCode, (k, v) -> {
                modifyValue(v, valueA, valueB, code);
                return v;
            });
        }
    
        private static void modifyValue(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Model> v, BigDecimal valueA, BigDecimal ValueB, String code) {
            v.compute(code, (k, val) -> {
                val.setCode(code);
                val.setValueA(valueA);
                val.setValueB(ValueB);
                return val;
            });
    
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting your data structure based on the code you're using to access it, you have an outer map from `String` codes to inner singleton maps, and each inner map maps exactly one code to a `Model`.  The `Model`s have multiple distinct properties that are to be updated, as a group, from time to time.  Each key of the outer map is the same as the single key of the corresponding inner map.  Each key of each inner map is the same as the `code` property of the corresponding `Model`.

I guess, then, the idea for the inner maps, which otherwise seem redundant, is to use their `ConcurrentHashMap.compute()` methods to perform modifications of multiple properties of the `Model` objects as atomic groups, without blocking concurrent modification of different `Model` objects.

> Multiple threads will try to update values of same mainCode, does below cause trouble?

[Each entire invocation of `ConcurrentHashMap.compute()` is performed atomically](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)), so multiple threads invoking `securities.compute()` via your `updateModel()` method, whether for the same or for different keys, will not interfere with each other with respect to the `securities` map itself.

Similarly, multiple threads concurrently invoking `modifyValue()` with the same first argument will not interfere with each other with respect to that map. The `Model`-property modifications will be performed as an atomic group *with respect to other operations on the map*.

But **that's not sufficient**.  If those properties of your `Model` objects are accessed by any other path (and surely they are at least *read* at some point), then that produces data races.  At minimum, those reads can observe inconsistent combinations of property values.

It might be possible to build sufficient additional infrastructure around this nested-map idea to serve all your needs without data races, but this cure is probably worse than the disease.  I see two potential approaches that are superior:

1. Make the `Model` objects immutable, and remove the inner maps (the outer map will map codes directly to `Model`s).  Instead of updating existing `Model` objects, *replace* them with new ones having the desired properties.

OR

2. Apply explicit locks or conventional synchronization appropriately to protect all accesses to the `Model` objects, and remove the inner maps.

If (1) is viable for you with respect to the other requirements of your application then that's what I would recommend.  If not, then probably there is no alternative better than (2).

Comment: I understand data races. Outer key is main key which have multiple Models. Inner key is code of models. Do you mean ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<Model> or ConcurrentHashMap<K, CopyOnWriteArrrayList<V>

Comment: @SmokingTurtle, this answer already expresses how I interpreted your data structure.  It sounds like you are saying that interpretation was incorrect.  Even if so, the bottom line is the same: make the `Model` objects immutable, and replace them at need instead of mutating them, OR use explicit locks or conventional synchronization appropriately to protect *all* accesses to those objects.  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not useful here, because you need to make copies of the `Model` objects themselves (for option 1) not of a collection containing them.